# Outputting byte[] to a .txt file

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to output a byte array to a file. The String that I create displays correctly when I call System.out.println(ouput_stream). Hover, it does not output correctly when I use a FileOutputStream. Here's what I've got so far. Any suggestions?

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("outputFile.txt"); 
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");

String received_string = new String(rPacket.getData(), 0, rPacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");

System.out.println(received_string);
out.write(received_string, 0, received_string.length());
```

The console displays the information the information when I call the System.out.println(received_string. However, it doesn't output the file correctly. I asked a similar question earlier, but now am struggling on the output. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Bytes aren't text.  What do you want to display?

Comment: Do you want to output a byte[] or a String?

Comment: You say "it doesn't output the file correctly".  What does the file contain after you close the writer?

Comment: There are asian looking characters there. Whereas the System.out.println outputs ASCII english characters.

Comment: The byte file is created from a similar file, and transferred across a network. The result I get is a byte array, I don't think there's much I can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Apache Commons [FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile%28java.io.File,%20byte%5B%5D,%20boolean%29)

Should do what you need

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a bit weird (do you want bytes or Strings), but should be okay.

What did you find in the file? Did you close the stream/writer before looking at it? If not, it is likely still being buffered somewhere.

Try to avoid the conversion to String, though, if you really want to just pipe that packet to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a String or a Writer at all. Just copy the bytes directly from the packet to the file:

```
fos.write(rPacket.getData(), rPacket.getOffset(), rPacket.getLength());
```

Then you can't possibly corrupt the data.

Answer (score -1):

Try using BufferedWriter ..

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfile"));
writer.write(received_string);
```

Comment: Using `FileWriter` will only make it worse, as it uses the platform default encoding, where the OP wants to use UTF-8.